# NodeJS Promise.all with promises created in a different module result in unhandled rejections

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

Im running node version 7.7.3 and bluebird version 3.5.0. I am running into issues with `Promise.all` when the promises are created in a module that I am importing. See the example code below.

This one fails:

```
// foo.js
const Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('why doesnt this work?'));
};

// test.js
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const foo = require('./foo');

const f1 = foo();

Promise.all([f1])
  .then(() => { })
  .catch(err => {
     // We expect this catch to handle the rejection.
     // This function is invoked, but node reports an unhandled rejection error
   });
```

However, this one passes. Note the only difference is that bar is not imported.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const bar = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { reject('but this works?!') });
};

const b1 = bar();

Promise.all([b1])
  .then(() => { })
  .catch(err => {
     // We get here without an unhandled rejection error.
  });
```

Comment: Is there anything else that might (try to) call `foo`? Try placing a `console.log()` or `console.trace()` in the function to make sure it's only called once.

Comment: This is full code? I can't replicate your error with this code

Comment: No, this test is part of a much bigger test suite, and the promise chain is nested a bit more (foo is returned up through about 3 more levels of promises). I tried to isolate the issue down for this SO post, but it looks like I did not succeed. I started a new node project with just the code posted and I cannot repro. I will work on a simplified test case and update the question.

Comment: I think I have narrowed it down to our usage of sinon to stub out some of the async behaviors that were happening in this test. I didnt think it was relevant to the setup when I originally posted this, but have since stumbled up on this: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/313. I am still not able to distill the issue down further to have a concise repro case... if I do, I will update this question.